# Proxy_pass nginx not found

Tags: node.js, nginx, routes, reverse-proxy, microservices

So, I was developing my server following the micro services arch in node. Therefore, I'm using nginx to redirect correctly the routes with each service. And was going pretty well since I added ghost on a subdirectory.

Now, Ghost is working perfectly but all the others routes are broken. The nginx answer is not found.

My nginx server congiguration:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html;
  }

  location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /tool/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8100/;
  }
}
```

Also I test the micro services with, ie:

```
telnet localhost 8100
```

Result it's ok.

I'm not even close to know what's happening, any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Also I notice that if I start a micro service on root, ie, the next routes try to follow the service instead of the nginx routing.

Comment: FYI, Nginx proxy_pass trailing slash makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Anatoly said **trailing slashes** make differences!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change Nginx config like as below:

```
listen 80;

server_name  <your pc name or localhost or 127.0.0.1>
```

Comment: okay, I think you can try to config log and re-produce, check the log status.     **error_log path**